# Why Laravel5.2 eloquent query builder showing different results in windows and linux?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have a field named 'status' in my table and the field type is 'tinyint', When I am trying to perform the where condition using eloquent query builder, it gives me different results in linux and windows.

Table structure:

[image]

and my code is,

```
Os::all()->where('status', 1);
```

It is working fine on windows machines and I am getting the results, but in Linux it returns empty collection.

then I tried

```
Os::all()->where('status', '1');
```

Its working fine on Linux, but not in windows :(

When I set the 'strict' flag to 'false'

```
Os::all()->where('status', 1, false);
```

it working fine on both platforms, Why is it so ?

Comment: I feel as though the environments are not the same. Are you aware that Laravel 5.3 changed the default behaviour of strict or loose matching for the `where()` method? Let me know if you have double checked that the version of Laravel and mysql are the same on both your Windows and Linux environments

Answer (score 1):

I think that problem is in 'status' variable type.

First of all, I want to be sure that you know that your condition *where('status', 1)* is not on eloquent query builder but on **Collection**.

*Os::all()* query returns [Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections) of elements and method *where('status', 1)* is working on this Collection (set of database data). **Where condition on collection != where condition in query builder**. If you want to make where on query builder please do it in this way:

```
Os::where('status', 1)->get();
```

I guess that problem is that in Windows 'status' variable is casting to integer but in Linux is casting to string. This is due to slightly diffrent mysql configuration. Now take a look at Collection where method and everything will be clear:

```
public function where($key, $value, $strict = true)
    {
        return $this->filter(function ($item) use ($key, $value, $strict) {
            return $strict ? data_get($item, $key) === $value
                           : data_get($item, $key) == $value;
        });
    }
```

When $strict = true method dont look at variable types.

How fix it?

You have probably few ways:

1. Unify mysql configuration - it could be hard.
2. Try query builder where: Os::where('status', 1)->get() - maybe in this way type casting will not be problem
3. Write attribute getter to change status attribute type in each time it is requested:

   public function getStatusAttribute($value)
       {
           return (int)$value;
       } You need choose to cast to (string) or (int). Keep in mind that status with changed type will not be visible in Collection but
   only in single model obiect. After adding this getter you will not
   need to add 'false' attribute to Collection where.